# AWS - Call the declared variable in another lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

So I have 3 lambdas that connects to the routes of the API Gateway. One(connectFunction)for $connect, One(disconnectFunction) for $disconnect, and another one(onMessageFunction) for my added route named onMessage.

My problem is I declared const usernameid=event.queryStringParameters.usernameid in my lambda for $connect and I will use that usernameid in my onMessage route. How can I do this?

Below is my snippet code for connectFunction lambda and onMessageFunction lambda:

*connectFunction*

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
    const connection_Id = event.requestContext.connection_Id;
    const usernameid = event.queryStringParameters.usernameid;
    addConnection(connection_Id,usernameid).then(() => {    
        callback(null, {        
            statusCode: 200,       
            });
    });};
```

*onMessageFunction*

```
let sending = undefined;
function init(event) {  
    const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
        apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
        endpoint: event.requestContext.domainName + '/' + event.requestContext.stage
    });      
    
    sending = async (connection_Id, data) => {  
        await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ 
            Connection_Id: connection_Id, 
            Data: `Echo: ${data}`}).promise();
        }}
```

The code is correct but the output is Echo: data and I want to be the username which I inputted and the data so dev(this is the username):data should be the output

Comment: The basic expectation you need to have for programming on Lambda is that every single Lambda invocation will be entirely standalone, and no data from any previous invocation will be available within the instance itself. If you need to persist data in any way, you need external storage like a database.

Comment: Hello. I already made a database using Dynamodb. So the username stored from the connect will be also called in onMessageFunction

Comment: Ideally, you would not have 3 API invocations. How are you expecting the connection that you created in the 1st invocation to be used in the 2nd, completely independent, invocation?